# Regular Expression naming capture group

Tags: regex

I have successfully written a regex pattern to scrape some value and it works really awesome but i am not getting how to name the capture group.

This is my string:

```
<div class="pipe-mailbody pipe-mailbody-2cccfb01-75f1-4fc0-9d5f-5f5ed8729d1b">Deal ID:<br>256<br><br>Deal pipeline ID:<br>3<br><br>Deal stage ID:<br>16<br><br>Deal contact person ID:<br>740<br><br>End:</div>
```

and this is my pattern:

```
Deal\sID\:\<br\>([\d]+)\<br\>[\<\>\d\w\s]+\:\<br\>([\d]+)<br><br>Deal\sstage\sID:<br\>([\d]+)<br\>[\d\s\>\<\S]+person\sID\:\<br>([\d]+)\<br\>
```

Can anyone help me how to name the capture group? like `([\d]+)` this is the one of capture group, i want to name it `person`

How can i achieve it?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: btw not all browsers support that

Comment: It depends upon the language which you are using to process these. You should be able to capture `group id`.` group(0)` is the captured string and `group(1)` is the first captured group.

Answer (score -1):

All right, well I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but hopefully this helps.

You can use something like a [`Pattern Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) in Java to get a value. A `Pattern` object in Java allows you to compile a regex pattern. The `Matcher` object then gets all matches of the pattern from a certain string. You can get a capture group using the `group` method of the `Matcher` object.

If this is your string:

```
<div class="pipe-mailbody pipe-mailbody-2cccfb01-75f1-4fc0-9d5f-5f5ed8729d1b">Deal ID:<br>256<br><br>Deal pipeline ID:<br>3<br><br>Deal stage ID:<br>16<br><br>Deal contact person ID:<br>740<br><br>End:</div>
```

With Java, you can do this (as a note, I also simplified your pattern, as there were a number of unnecessary escape characters):

```
String input = "<div class="pipe-mailbody pipe-mailbody-2cccfb01-75f1-4fc0-9d5f-5f5ed8729d1b">Deal ID:<br>256<br><br>Deal pipeline ID:<br>3<br><br>Deal stage ID:<br>16<br><br>Deal contact person ID:<br>740<br><br>End:</div>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Deal\sID:<br>(\d+)<br>.+:<br>(\d+)<br><br>Deal\sstage\sID:<br>(\d+)<br>.+person\sID:<br>(\d+)<br>";

Matcher m = p.match(input);

String person = m.group(4);
```

This saves the person ID in a String variable.